# Regular expression not working properly for some scenarios

Tags: java, regex

asRuleValue is `[^0-9a-zA-Z"'-.#, ]`

```
Pattern classPattern = Pattern.compile(asRuleValue, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = classPattern.matcher(asValue);
if (!m.find())
{
   lbFlag = true;
}
```

is not working properly for some scenarios like for `()` what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to escape the `-` in your character class or put it to the end.

Use:

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z"'.#, -]
```

otherwise you are creating a character range from `'` to `.` that includes also `()*+,`